# Is it possible to declare generic delegate with no parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, func

I have...

```
Func<string> del2 = new Func<string>(MyMethod);
```

and I really want to do..

```
Func<> del2 = new Func<>(MyMethod);
```

so the return type of the callback method is void. Is this possible using the generic type func?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Func` family of delegates is for methods that take zero or more parameters and return a value. For methods that take zero or more parameters an don't return a value use one of the `Action` delegates. If the method has no parameters, use [the non-generic version of `Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
Action del = MyMethod;
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes a function returning void (no value) is a `Action`

```
public Test()
{
    // first approach
    Action firstApproach = delegate
    {
        // do your stuff
    };
    firstApproach();

    //second approach 
    Action secondApproach = MyMethod;
    secondApproach();
}

void MyMethod()
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

**hope this helps**

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. You can't just leave the type parameters like that. And why do you have both `Action` and `Func` in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Action delegate type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In cases where you're 'forced' to use `Func<T>`, e.g. in an internal generic API which you want to reuse, you can just define it as `new Func<object>(() => { SomeStuff(); return null; });`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code example using Lambda expressions instead of Action/Func delegates.

```
delegate void TestDelegate();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TestDelegate testDelegate = () => { /*your code*/; };

  testDelegate();
}
```

Comment: Do mention how your code is different from other answers (this one using Lambda instead of Action/Func delegates)

Comment: Do you mean editing my proposed answer by adding "here is a code example using Lambda expressions instead of Action/Func delegates" or do you want me to justify me posting my answer Feeling it is a duplicate of another answer?
Any way thank you for your feedback! - I'm new D: